# Resque Scheduler - NoMethodError "run_before_delayed_enqueue_hooks"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Resque and ResqueScheduler to queue re-occurring jobs. I'm on rails 3.2.6, resque 1.21.0, resque-scheduler 2.0.0h

When the scheduler is started I get the following error, also having problems getting the schedule tab to show up(after following the doco):

rake resque:scheduler --trace
** Invoke resque:scheduler (first_time)
** Invoke resque:scheduler_setup (first_time)
** Execute resque:scheduler_setup
** Invoke resque:setup (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute resque:setup
** Execute resque:scheduler
2012-07-07 23:55:56 Loading Schedule
2012-07-07 23:55:56 Scheduling run_pinpro_copy 
2012-07-07 23:55:56 Scheduling CancelAbandonedOrders 
2012-07-07 23:55:56 Schedules Loaded
2012-07-07 23:56:30 queueing Testing (run_database_copy)
**2012-07-07 23:56:30 NoMethodError: undefined method `run_before_delayed_enqueue_hooks' for ResqueScheduler::Plugin:Module**

**resque_scheduler.yml**

```
CancelAbandonedOrders:
  cron: "*/5 * * * *"

run_database_copy:
  cron: "30 * * * * *"
  class: Testing
  queue: testing_queue
  args:
  description: "Copy PinPro views to local tables"
```

**testing.rb (worker)**

```
class Testing
  @queue = :testing_queue
  def self.perform
    puts "Running Job!"
  end
end
```

**resque.rb**

```
require 'resque_scheduler'

Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'config/resque_scheduler.yml'))
```

**resque_scheduler.rake**

```
# Resque tasks
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque_scheduler/tasks'
require 'resque_scheduler/server'

task "resque:setup" => :environment

namespace :resque do
  task :setup do
    require 'resque'
    require 'resque_scheduler'
    require 'resque/scheduler'
    require 'resque_scheduler/server'

    # you probably already have this somewhere
    Resque.redis = 'localhost:6379'
  end
end
```

Any examples/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my Ruby Version was not correct. Using RVM now to manage different versions(highly recommended). I should have been using ruby v1.9.3